# Comprobacion de usuarios PHP por nombre y por id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

estoy creando una aplicacion web en la cual necesito poder registrar un tipo concreto de usuarios en los cuales el nombre puede estar repetido pero el id que tienen asignado no. La tabla en la que se almacenan tiene la siguiente estructura:
id_usuario int auto_increment primary key
nombre varchar(100) not null
El problema es que yo cuando registro un usuario quiero consultar en mi base de datos que no exista un nombre con ese id, pero a su vez debe permitir ingresar varios usuarios con el mismo nombre pero diferente id.
En fin no se como escribir el codigo php que me verifique eso, o si ahi alguna manera mas sencilla de lograr este fin.
Muchas gracias por las molestias, un saludo a la comunidad.

Comment: esto que pones no suena nada lógico "El problema es que yo cuando registro un usuario quiero consultar en mi base de datos que no exista un nombre con ese id, pero a su vez debe permitir ingresar varios usuarios con el mismo nombre pero diferente id"

Comment: quizas, si haces un constrain desde la base de datos te aseguras que la combinacion entre el id_usuario y el nombre sean unicos. CONSTRAINT nombreConstraint UNIQUE(id_usuario , nombre).

Comment: Pero si el id es auto incremental, significa que el id siempre va a ser diferente independientemente si el nombre del usuario se repite, entonces la consulta que hagas siempre es falsa nunca te va a arrojar un valor.

Comment: Hola pablito-clavo-un-clavito, te sugiero revisar [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas y obtengas respuestas de calidad.